# em.persist seems doesn't persist data on postgreSQL db

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm, jpa

I've got a simple java main which must write bean data on a PostgreSQL database. I use Entity manager to persist or update object. I use hibernate and toplink driver connection which are specified in persistence.xml file. 
When I call em.persist(obj), nothing is saved on database, I don't know why. here is my simple code:

```
private static void importa(FileReader f) throws IOException {

  EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
  .createEntityManagerFactory("orpt2");
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

dispositivoMedico = new DispositivoMedico();
dispositivoMedico.setCategoria("prova");
dispositivoMedico.setCodice("323");
em.persist(dispositivoMedico);
```

And here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="orpt2">
   <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.AccessoriScheda</class>
    <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.CampiSchede</class>
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.CampiSchedeSalvati</class>
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.CampoAggiuntivo</class> 
   <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.Categorie</class>
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.CategorieCampi</class>
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.CategorieCampiPK</class>
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.ClasseCivab</class> 
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.DecodificaStato</class>
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.DispositivoMedico</class>
   <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.Ente</class>
    <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.FormaNegoziazione</class>
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.Fornitore</class> 
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.LogSession</class> 
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.Modello</class> 
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.Periodicita</class>
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.Produttore</class>
   <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.Ruolo</class>
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.RuoloPK</class>
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.RuoloUtente</class> 
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.Scheda</class>
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.SchedaSalvata</class>
  <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.Tipologia</class> 
   <class>it.ariadne.orpt2.entities.Utente</class>

  <!-- locale 2010--><!-- optsanmatteo_prova300310 -->
   <properties>

   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"
    value="org.postgresql.Driver" />

   <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
    value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/optsanmatteo_provaHash" />

   <property name="hibernate.connection.password"
    value="s4sh4gr3y" />

   <property name="hibernate.connection.username"
    value="sanmatteo" />

   <property name="hibernate.dialect"
    value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />


   <property name="toplink.logging.level" value="WARNING" />
   <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver"
    value="org.postgresql.Driver" />

   <property name="toplink.jdbc.url"
    value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/optsanmatteo_provaHash" />

   <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="s4sh4gr3y" />

   <property name="toplink.jdbc.user"
    value="sanmatteo" />
  </properties>

 </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Thank you for your help.

Mario

Answer (score 2):

First, the [`persist`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist(java.lang.Object)), [`merge`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge(T)), [`remove`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) operations won't hit the database  directly, they change the state of objects in memory - in the persistence context (the transaction). When the transaction is [committed](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityTransaction.html#commit()), or if the persistence context is [*flushed*](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush%28%29), then the changes are written to the database.

Second, the [`persist`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist(java.lang.Object)) operation can only be called within a transaction, an exception will be thrown outside of a transaction. So you need to start a transaction.

Here is a modified example:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("orpt2");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin(); // start a transaction

dispositivoMedico = new DispositivoMedico();
dispositivoMedico.setCategoria("prova");
dispositivoMedico.setCodice("323");

em.persist(dispositivoMedico);

em.getTransaction().commit(); // Commit the current resource transaction, writing
                              // any unflushed changes to the database.
```

Answer (score 1):

em.persist doesn't persist the object, it marks it as persistable and at the commit the object will be persisted.

I assume from your code fragment you don't have a commit?

```
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();

dispositivoMedico = new DispositivoMedico(); dispositivoMedico.setCategoria("prova"); dispositivoMedico.setCodice("323");
em.persist(dispositivoMedico);

tx.commit();
em.close();
```

Comment: When I run the main java, I think there is a problem during query execution. When I do tx.commit(), the application takes a lot of time to execute query and doesn't get any error. It seems like there some conflicts between the toplink and hibernate. What can I do?

Thank you for your help